# ZMQ Pub Sub - Should it be dropping messages?

Tags: java, publish, zeromq, subscribe

Was trying to test a simple implementation of pub/sub. I am finding that if I leave subscriber up and send messages, they are not all received by Subscriber. Sometimes all are received, sometimes partial, sometimes whole set is not received.

Run the Subscriber ( leave it running) , followed by running the Publisher multiple times.

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Context;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket;


public static void main (String[] args) {

    // Prepare our context and subscriber
    Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    Socket subscriber = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);

    subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5563");
    subscriber.subscribe("B".getBytes());


    System.out.println("Starting Subscriber..");
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        String address = subscriber.recvStr();
        String contents = subscriber.recvStr();
        System.out.println(address+":"+new String(contents) + ": "+(i));
        i++;
    }

}
```

}

Publisher:

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Context;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket;


public class TestPublisher {

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    Socket publisher = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB);
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5563");
    System.out.println("Starting Publisher..");
    publisher.setIdentity("B".getBytes());
    publisher.setHWM(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(10l);
        publisher.sendMore("B");
        boolean isSent = publisher.send("We would like to see this:"+i);
        System.out.println("Message was sent "+i+" , "+isSent);
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    publisher.close ();
    context.term ();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of debugging found the issue to be that when publishing the socket binding took a bit of time and trying to publish just discarded the message.  Adding a simple sleep of 100ms on the initial bind fixed this. In a prod environment, the publisher would be already bound at startup.

Guess it was a one line solution. Now all the messages for a pub/sub with average data volumes works just fine without any data loss. See code snippet update for my publisher below.

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Context;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket;


public class TestPublisher {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
        Socket publisher = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB);

        publisher.bind("tcp://*:5563");
        System.out.println("Starting Publisher..");
        publisher.setIdentity("B".getBytes());
        // for testing setting sleep at 100ms to ensure started.
        Thread.sleep(100l);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            publisher.sendMore("B");
            boolean isSent = publisher.send("X("+System.currentTimeMillis()+"):"+i);
            System.out.println("Message was sent "+i+" , "+isSent);
        }

        publisher.close ();
        context.term ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reliable pub/sub is covered in chapter 5 "Advanced Pub-Sub Patterns" of the [zmq guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all). But if your server is always up and running in production, you don't need to do anything more than the sleep you've already put in to get your tests working.

If you really wanted to solve the problem of subscribers mising messages, the "Getting an Out-of-Band Snapshot" example in chapter 5 covers it.